# C If Loop Fails to Set Struct Data

Tags: c, struct

This has stumped me for a few days now. I have tried searching but have turned up mostly just definitions for `struct`...

In an if loop I set 2 struct variables, but neither of them come out correct. `guests[x].plusone` is stuck at 0 and `guests[x].plusonefood` is simply empty. If I set them (with the same line) outside of the loop, however, there are no issues. My compiler shows no warnings or errors. What am I missing?

This is my first project with C, so please point out anything else you notice, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct guestinfo
{
    char name[50];
    short int plusone;
    char food[50];
    char plusonefood[50];
};

char temp[5];

char setfood (int f)
{
    char foodtemp[f];

    int x;
    for (x=0; x < f; x++)
    {
        printf("Food option %d:\n", (x+1));
        fgets(&foodtemp[x],100,stdin);
    }

    return *foodtemp;
}

int main ()
{

    int number_of_rsvp=0;
    int number_of_food=0;

    printf("Number of food choices:\n");
    fgets(temp,5,stdin);
    number_of_food = atoi (temp);

    while (number_of_food <= 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a number greater than 0\n");
        fgets(temp,5,stdin);
        number_of_food = atoi (temp);
    }

    char food [50] [number_of_food];
    **food = setfood(number_of_food);

    printf("Number of RSVPs:\n");
    fgets(temp,5,stdin);
    number_of_rsvp = atoi (temp);

    while (number_of_rsvp <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a number greater than 0\n");
        fgets(temp,5,stdin);
        number_of_rsvp = atoi (temp);
    };

    struct guestinfo guests[number_of_rsvp];

        int x;
        int f;
        for (x=0; x < number_of_rsvp; x++)
        {
            // add input validation to this section
            printf("Guest Number %d:\n\nGuest Name:\n", (x+1));
            fgets(guests[x].name,50,stdin);
            printf("Food Choice #:\n");
            fgets(temp,3,stdin);
            f = atoi(temp);
            f--;
            *guests[x].food = food [50] [f];
            printf("Plus One? Y/N\n");
            fgets(temp,3,stdin);
        }

            if (strchr (temp,'Y') != NULL || strchr (temp,'y') != NULL) //This loop
            {
                guests[x].plusone = 1;
                printf("Plus one food choice #:\n");
                fgets(temp,3,stdin);
                f = atoi(temp);
                f--;
                *guests[x].plusonefood = food [50] [f];
            }

            else if (strchr (temp,'N') != NULL || strchr (temp,'n') != NULL)
            {
                guests[x].plusone = 0;
            };


    FILE *guestlist = fopen ("guestlist.txt","w");
// debugging
    printf("%d\n",guests[0].plusone);
    printf("%s\n",guests[0].plusonefood);


    for (x=0; x < number_of_rsvp; x++)
    {
        fprintf(guestlist,"Guest Number %d:\n\nName: %s\nFood Choice: %s\n",(x+1),guests[x].name,guests[x].food);

    switch (guests[x].plusone)
    {
        case 1:
        {
        fprintf(guestlist,"Plus One: Yes\n\tPlus One Food: %s\n\n",guests[x].plusonefood);
        break;
        }
        case 0:
        {
        fprintf(guestlist,"Plus One: No\n\n");
        break;
        }
        default:
        {
        break;
        }
    }
    }

    fclose (guestlist);

    printf("Printing Guest List...\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `setfood()` returns pointer to local variable (i.e. this part of memory might be overwritten). You have to allocate memory to fix it! Read about `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: Yep local variable came back and bit me. Learning how to `malloc` 2d array now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing an invalid memory place.
The array has `number_of_rsvp` elements.
Your `for()` loop interates over the variable `x` up to the value `number_of_rsvp` and exits.
After that, the value of `x` is equal to `number_of_rsvp`.
Since the index of the array only can go from `0` to `number_of_rsvp - 1`, the element `guests[x]`, which is `guests[number_of_rsvp]`, is out-of-bound.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. So moving the if loop inside the for loop should fix it right?

Comment: The `if()` sentence moved inside the `for()` loop will fix, of course, the problem you are having with the access to an out-of-limits element of the array. However, if this is the right thing to do or not it depends on the logic of the program. I will not analize that aspect. Just, observe if you need to have the `if()` block inside the loop or not.

Comment: I did actually. I thought it was when I tried to have that whole for loop as a separate function but I was having issues returning the final struct array properly. Maybe something got lost in translation I guess.